I am trying to prove this inequality, but I don't know where I went wrong...
Here's the inequality I am attempting to prove: Let $x_i>0$ for $i=1,2,3 \dots n$. Prove that
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=1}^n (x^{19}_k) \sum_{k=1}^n (x^{93}_k) \geq \sum_{k=1}^n (x^{20}_k) \sum_{k=1}^n (x^{92}_k)
\end{equation*}
(Note: This inequality is correct and it does have proof, I am just not writing it down)
Here's how I attempt to solve it: First, we apply the AM-GM inequality to the left-hand side to obtain
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=1}^n (x^{19}_k) \sum_{k=1}^n (x^{93}_k) \leq \left[\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n x^{19}_k+x^{93}_k\right]^2
\end{equation*}
Now, Applying the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality to the right-hand side, I get
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=1}^n (x^{20}_k) \sum_{k=1}^n (x^{92}_k) \geq \left[\sum_{k=1}^n x^{56}_k \right]^2
\end{equation*}
Applying some rules of inequalities (I think) we find that to prove our claim, it is sufficient enough to show that
\begin{equation*}
\left[\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n x^{19}_k+x^{93}_k\right]^2 \geq \left[\sum_{k=1}^n x^{56}_k \right]^2
\end{equation*}
Since all $x_i>0$, these sums must be greater than zero, so we may remove the square on both sides and multiply by 2, we get
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=1}^n x^{19}_k+x^{93}_k \geq \sum_{k=1}^n 2x^{56}_k
\end{equation*}
Moving the right-hand-side to the left-hand side
we get
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=1}^n x^{93}_k-2x^{56}_k+x^{19}_k \geq 0
\end{equation*}
We observe that for any $x$, $x^{93}-2x^{56}+x^{19}$ factorizes into a perfect square $(x^{93/2}-x^{19/2})^2$$. This is always greater than zero by trivial inequality, so we've proven our inequality above and therefore our claim. Or have we? In our original claim, we assumed the right-hand side was greater than the left-hand side, but what if we make a false assumption and assume the left-hand side is greater than the right-hand side? Well, the calculations are much of the same, rather we use the AM-GM on the right-hand-side and the Cauchy-Schwartz on the left-hand-side, and we simplify as we did before, we want to prove that
\begin{equation*}
 \left[\sum_{k=1}^n x^{56}_k \right]^2 \leq  \left[ \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^n x^{20}_k+x^{92}_k \right]^2
\end{equation*}
Again, doing the same thing as we did last time and noticing that $x^{92}-2x^{56}+x^{20}=(x^{46}-x^{10})^2$. By the trivial inequality, we have just proven this inequality to be true and therefore we have also proven our false claim??!!??!?? Now, for the culminating question, if I did anything wrong, what is it? If I didn't make an error, why doesn't this approach work?

Try out all your inequalities with the simple example $n=2$, $x_1=1$, $x_2=2$. Some of them are false, and this will give clues about where your reasoning was wrong.

Alright I will try

Alright, to be honest, I tried this on every single inequality, including the claim to verify its authenticity and I found all of them to be correct. Would you mind pointing out which inequality is wrong so I can focus on it and find out why?

Actually, probably just your "false claim" is false. But your inequalities don't actually imply the original goal.

A little late, but to be honest, you are completely right!  I believe you can also 'prove' the equality with the signs flipped with my method. Thank you.

Too bad you deleted your question about $(1+\sqrt5)^n$.  It should be better received now that you showed your answer, and I have an answer not involving Fibonacci numbers
